# Variate for a deterministic system?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, terminology, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I have five math terminology questions about variables, realizations, variates / outcomes, and I have based my questions off my understanding of these terms from [1] 2014 MIT paper "Random Variables in a Nutshell" by AT Patera, M Yano, page 3 first paragraph:

QUESTION 1: Are "realizations", "outcomes", and “variate” strictly only applicable in the context of probability & statistics / stochastic / randomness?

QUESTION 2: Would it make sense to use these words in the context of a deterministic model?

QUESTION 3: are variates just discrete values or can they be continuous values, and if continuous then what physical example would the latter be? I base this question off my understanding of what variates are as listed in the second indented bullet below.

QUESTION 4: So would the following be true: "yielded deterministic-outcomes (e.g. discrete numerical values) from deterministic-realizations just be known as deterministic-variates"

QUESTION 5: It appears deterministic probabilities do exist [4], does anyone have any more references on that?

---

From [1], it is my understanding that:

- Variables are just the description of in/dependency's variation, x or X
- Realizations are the procedure of applying that variable to a specific instance/event/condition, x -> x^i
- Variate is an outcome as yielded from processing their realizations, x^i -> x^i_o elements of sample space {x^i_o}

---

Also, I am citing the MIT paper here and also these forums where it is being asked if variate, and covariant has meaning for deterministic systems:

[1] https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-086-numerical-computation-for-mechanical-engineers-fall-2014/nutshells-guis/MIT2_086F14_Random_Var.pdf

[2] [What is the difference between a random variate and realization of a random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302622/what-is-the-difference-between-a-random-variate-and-realization-of-a-random-vari/4333225#4333225)

[3] https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172498/variance-and-covariance-in-the-context-of-deterministic-variables

[4] http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/12166/1/DeterminismIndeterminismWordPittsburghArchiveWithF.pdf

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204705/16397

Comment: TY @r.e.s It has been my understanding that random variates are just outcomes / results of a realization, but aren’t necessarily caused by or much less even correlated to an input random variable to a system. But I do like that block diagrams from what I have seen tend to always represent cause & effect relationships of variables nicely, input->system->output.